# behavior of derivative at infinity

Tags: real-analysis

Edit: Is it true that given a differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim_{x\to +\infty}(f(x)+f'(x))=l\in \mathbb{R}$, it follows that $\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=l$? Can I see a proof or a contrexample?

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ a real valued everywhere differentiable function. Let $f'$ be its derivative. It looks quite clear that the behavior of $f'$ at infinity is of lower order than $f$. More specifically: $\lim_{x\to +\infty}(f(x)+f'(x))=\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)$ provided that $\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)$ exists. How can we show more generally that if $\lim_{x\to +\infty}(f(x)+f'(x))=l\in \mathbb{R}$, then necessarily $\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=l$ as well? The task is easy if one assumes that $\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)$ exists or in case of non existence if $f(x)+f'(x)=l$ from a certain $x$ sufficiently big, but is there an elegant argument not involving a case by case analysis?

Comment: You edited the question after receiving an answer which is, at least to some extent, invalidated by your edit. This is not very nice. The first claim, with which your original question started (''it looks quite clear" ..  provided the limit of $f$ exists) is not true, a counter example is given in my answer (which I will now delete).

Comment: I edited because your answer does not address the main question and your (nice) example is NOT a counterexample of the main statement: $\lim_{x\to +\infty}(f(x)+f'(x))$ must be a real value by hypothesis and this is NOT satisfied by your example $f(x)=\frac{\sin(x^{2})}{x}$. I do not see why I should not insist if the answer I receive does not seem to address my question and in any case your answer has not been invalidated at all: it is perfectly clear that the edit is stressing the main question and the initial form has not been touched and remains available

Comment: This is a famous question. A simple solution is via L'Hospital's Rule by writing $f(x) =\dfrac{e^xf(x)} {e^x} $.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an increasing function or a decreasing function then f'(infinity)=0, assuming the limit converges to a finite real number, and so your equation would be true.
If the function ossicillates then it would not be the case as shown in the above counterexample.

Comment: It is not a counterexample because $\lim_{x\to +\infty}(f(x)+f'(x))$ in that case does not exists, it is $\lim_{x\to +\infty}2\cos(x^{2})$. The assumption is that $\lim_{x\to +\infty}(f(x)+f'(x))$ exists and it is equal to a given real number